# User Registration with URI issue

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

so this is a tough question for me to ask because the issue is not clear to me. The logcat just rapidly spits out lines and lines of errors with no clear explanation of what is wrong.

I have been trying to make it so when a user registers, a default avatar is added to their account, but for some reason when I add a default URI to the accounts, the registration fails. The app does not crash, and the account is created, but the user is not properly added to my Firebase Database and no authentication email is sent to the User.

So, to create this default avatar I have uploaded an image to my Firebase Storage, and I have converted the URL of the image to an URI by doing this

```
public Uri defaultAvatar = Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fifty-fifty-1314c.appspot.com/o/defaultavatarmale.png?alt=media&token=def5ee33-6664-4344-bfca-27e4b284df00");
```

And then, when a user hits register their account is created and is supposed to be added to the database using this line

```
User users = new User(username, email, defaultAvatar, wins, losses, balance, null, 0, false);
```

Whenever the spot that says `defaultAvatar` is null, the account registration works perfectly, but whenever I change it to that URI it crashes things. This is the entire method that registers a user

```
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                sendVerificationEmail();
                //start profile activity here

                User users = new User(username, email, defaultAvatar, wins, losses, balance, null, 0, false);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(users)
                        .addOnCompleteListener
                                (new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "A verification link has been sent to your email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration not successful, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

And the line that is giving me an error is:

```
.setValue(users)
```

My logcat that is supposed to help me out in this situation, is just a total mess whenever someone tries to register. I have tried to filter things in it to find a specific error, but nothing seems to be working. The Logcat has so much in it that the lines at the top start disappearing immediately so I can't see the initial error. If someone can help me narrow down the problem in my logcat that would be appreciated too!

I would show what my logcat says but I do not think it is useful in any way at the moment

```
2019-01-12 15:30:57.949 3149-3149/com.example.brent.fifty_fifty E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:663)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
```

User class:

```
package com.example.brent.fifty_fifty;
```

import android.net.Uri;

import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;

```
public class User {

HomePage hp;
private String email;
private String userName;
private String uid;
private String gameId;
private String currentGameID;
private int position;

private boolean ready, inGame;

private String HorT;
private int wins, losses, score;
private double balance;

private Uri profileImage;

public User() {

}

public User(String userName, int score, String HorT, String uid, String gameId, int position, boolean ready, boolean inGame) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
    this.HorT = HorT;
    this.gameId = gameId;
    this.ready = ready;
    this.position = position;
    this.inGame = inGame;
}

public User(String userName, String email, Uri profileImage, int wins, int losses, double balance, String currentGameID, int position, boolean inGame) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.email = email;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.losses = losses;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.currentGameID = currentGameID;
    this.position = position;
    this.inGame = inGame;
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getWins() {
    return wins;
}

public void setWins(int wins) {
    this.wins = wins;
}

public int getLosses() {
    return losses;
}

public void setLosses(int losses) {
    this.losses = losses;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}


public String getHorT() {
    return HorT;
}

public void setHorT(String horT) {
    HorT = horT;
}

public String getUid() {
    uid = hp.uid;
    return uid;
}


public String getGameId() {
    return gameId;
}

public void setGameId(String gameId) {
    this.gameId = gameId;
}


public String getCurrentGameID() {
    return currentGameID;
}

public void setCurrentGameID(String currentGameID) {
    this.currentGameID = currentGameID;
}


public boolean isReady() {
    return ready;
}

public void setReady(boolean ready) {
    this.ready = ready;
}

public boolean inGame() {
    return inGame;
}

public void inGame(boolean inGame) {
    this.inGame = inGame;
}

public int getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int position) {
    this.position = position;
}


public Uri getProfileImage() {
    return profileImage;
}

public void setProfileImage(Uri profileImage) {
    this.profileImage = profileImage;
}

}
```

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to try to understand what's in the log, because without an error message, we can only guess.

Comment: @DougStevenson I pasted a snippit of the logcat, but there are 7000 more lines that are basically just repeats of the snippit

Comment: What is your Users class?

Comment: @DougStevenson added it to the bottom of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Realtime Database SDK isn't dealing with the Uri object very well.  It's trying to perform a complex serialization of all of its data exposed by all of its getter methods.  Instead, you should specify the type of the avatar field to just be a string, because that's all you really want to store.  Either that, or create a Map of all the fields you want to serialize, and make sure they have the simple types of data you want to store for the user.

Comment: So, if I change the URI type to a String and store the URL's just as strings, then to display the avatars as images should I just convert them back to URI's just where the images are being displayed? Would that work

Comment: Yes, if you need a Uri, just convert it.